# Impact of using SHM_HUGE_1GB for a size much smaller than 1GB (say, 64MB)

Tags: c, system-calls, shared-memory

I'm relatively new to actually using (not understanding) a shared memory in Linux. I'm dealing with the situation now where I need to allocate a contiguous chunk of shared 64MB memory. While picking up how to properly use shared memories, I stumbled upon some huge TLB options for `shmget`; `SHM_HUGE_2MB` and `SHM_HUGE_1GB` (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html).

Now, I know how a huge TLB can be very beneficial for a large, contiguous memory (because the virtual-to-physical address translation gets much simpler). My question is, does it have an undesirable side effect if I use `SHM_HUGE_1GB` for a mere 64MB of memory? Or am I even allowed to use it for a smaller-sized memory?